# Chosen multiselect widget gets cleared on form submit in MVC 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen multiselect widget on my MVC view with the following html.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Branch, new SelectList(ViewBag.Branches, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "chzn-select-deselect", data_placeholder = "Select Branch", @multiple = "true" })
```

And I am having refresh icon on the view having input type submit; on click of which i have following code.

```
$("#dbRefresh").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var Form = $("form[id='FrmDashBoard']");
        Form.validate();
        if (Form.valid()) {
            Form.find('ul').empty();
            var fromDate = $("#FromDate").val();
            var toDate = $("#ToDate").val();
            var BranchList = $("#Branch").val();//chosen multiselect widget                
            var BranchString = "";
            if (BranchList != null)
                $.each(BranchList, function (index, item) {
                    BranchString += item + ",";
                });

            if (BranchString.length > 0)
                BranchString = BranchString.slice(0, -1);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("SetDashBord_DateFilter", "Home")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { FromDate: fromDate, ToDate: toDate, Branches: BranchString }
            });
            DisplayPOXOrderStatistics(fromDate, toDate, BranchString);
            DisplayPOXCompletedOrdersData(fromDate, toDate, BranchString);
            DisplayHSTOrderStatisticsData(fromDate, toDate, BranchString);
            DisplayPOXCompletedOrderPieChart(fromDate, toDate, BranchString);
            DisplayCurrentYearlyTrends(BranchString);
        }
        $("#Branch").trigger("liszt:updated");
        return false;
    });
```

where in all the functions called above are doing just ajax call & onsuccess of which the some parts of html from this view is updated(inner html of some div elements).

The problem I have with chosen multiselect of Branch is that when I click the refresh button; all li elements of ul having class chzn-choices get cleared. Because of which chosen widget appears as thick line on screen i.e height of ul element set to 0 due to li elements deletion. Can anybody suggest me whats going wrong with the chosen widget?

Comment: I don't imagine that to be a Chosen problem. Even in cases where the select list is empty, Chosen will still display a single-line height input element. My best guess is that there's actually a problem in your DOM manipulation, but there's no actual code provided here for that. Post the functions that actually do the work, so we can see where the problem might be.

Comment: Yes you are right, I got my mistake. In click event of refresh icon I was clearing ul elements within form.Which was clearing my chosen widget ul too. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my mistake. In click event of refresh icon I was clearing ul elements within form.
Which was clearing my chosen widget ul too.
I modified my refresh button click event to remove statement

```
Form.find('ul').empty();
```

This was used to clear all error messages displayed previously on the form & proceed further with valid user input.
Instead clearing the ul now I used the following code to remove error class applied to controls; so that error message will be removed from validation summary.

```
$('.input-validation-error')
           .removeClass('input-validation-error');
$(".validation-summary-errors")
.removeClass("validation-summary-errors")
.addClass("validation-summary-valid");
```